# Why is it necessary for parent class to have a default constructor if we do not create child class object in child class?

Tags: java

```
class handleException extends Exception
{
    public handleException(String s)
    {
        super(s);
    }
}

public class unhandled extends handleException {
    public static void main(String args[])throws handleException
    {
        float a=7/0;
        if(Double.isNaN(a))
        {
            throw new handleException("Exception is handled");
        }
    }


}
```

This code gives compile error saying that handleException which is the parent class does not have any default constructor ,but why is it so when child class constructor  unhandled() is not called, so super() will not be called so why is it giving compile time error .

Comment: Not sure I understand your question please clarify what you mean.

Comment: Sidenote: Please stick to Java naming conventions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically currently you're dealing with only one type of constructor, i.e., `Parameterized Constructor` but actually there are two types of constructors.

1. Default Constructor
2. Parameterized Constructor

[image: Types of constructors in java]

The main point to note here is:

> Rule: If there is no constructor in a class, compiler automatically creates a default constructor.

Now you don't have any constructor defined your your class `unhandled`. So compiler will automatically create a constructor like this:

```
public class unhandled extends handleException {

    //added by compiler
    public unhandled() { 
        super(); //note that this super will call the non-parameterized constructor of your parent class, i.e., handleException
    }

    public static void main(String args[])throws handleException
    {
        float a=7/0;
        if(Double.isNaN(a))
        {
            throw new handleException("Exception is handled");
        }
    }
}
```

now the word `super()` doesn't have any arguments and so it's invoking the default OR non parameterized constructor of your parent class, and since your parent class `handleException` don't have that, so the compiler says:

```
Sorry, but `handleException` don't have a default constructor, I can't invoke that.
```

Answer (score 5):

Because you haven't specified *any* constructor for `unhandled`, the compiler supplied the [default one](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9) for you, which in this case looks like this:

```
public unhandled() { // It's public because `unhandled` is public
    super();
}
```

The default constructor has no parameters, expects its superclass to have a no-parameters constructor, and has the same accessibility as the class. The compiler inserts this whether your code calls that constructor or not; it's not a "sometimes yes, sometimes no" thing. :-) Since the superclass `unhandledException` doesn't have a constructor with no parameters, the compiler can't compile the inserted default constructor.

If you want `unhandled` to only be constructed with parameters, you need to supply a constructor with parameters.

Alternately, if you want `unhandled` never to be constructed, you need to supply a constructor (presumably with no parameters) that's private: `private unhandled() { super(null); }`.

---

You might be wondering why the default constructor always has no parameters and expects the superclass constructor to have no parameters. The answer is: Because that's how it's designed. :-) It *could* have been designed to be more complicated. For instance, they could have based the default constructor on the available constructors in the superclass, but that's more complicated in terms of writing the compiler, and more complicated in terms of understanding how things work. Instead, it's kept simple, and if you want a different constructor, you just supply one.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `unhandled` does not have any constructor and Java will create a default one for you with no parameters. That default constructor want to call `super()` and that's why it is looking for nullary constructor in `handleException`. See also Java Language Specification https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9